# Is there anyway to give cmd prompt command in java

Tags: java, file-io, path

I'm trying to run cmd prompt command using java, i have a source path and destination path and i'm flippig the image. Flipped image should get copied to destination. The image is getting copied but not the flipped image. I'll share my code below, kindly let me know if anything else is needed.

```
@Test
public void executeCommandJpgDifferentPaths() throws IOException{
    Path resourceDirectory = Paths.get("src\\main\\resources\\download.jpg");
    Path destination = Paths.get(demoFolder.getAbsolutePath(),"download_output.jpg");
    String command = "magick convert -flip resourceDirectory destination " ;
    Boolean output = flipImplementation.executeCommand(command);
    Files.copy(resourceDirectory,destination);
    Assert.assertTrue(output);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(123456789L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this using, 'destinationDirectory.resolve'.We need to use as below :

```
 @Test
public void executeCommandJpgDifferentPaths() throws IOException{
    Path resourceDirectory = Paths.get("src\\main\\resources");
    Path resourcePath = resourceDirectory.resolve("download.jpg");
    Path destinationDirectory = Paths.get(demoFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    Path destinationPath = destinationDirectory.resolve("download_output.jpg");
    String command = "magick convert -flip " + resourcePath + " " + destinationPath ;
    Boolean output = flipImplementation.executeCommand(command);
    Assert.assertTrue(output);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(123456789L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a plain string. But you should be using variables inside.

Replace

```
String command = "magick convert -flip resourceDirectory destination " ;
```

with

```
String command = "magick convert -flip " + resourceDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + " " + destination.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, when i use resourceDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), it's asking me to rename reference. I tried with '+ resourceDirectory', it's throwing an exception as below

Comment: C:\Users\chitr\AppData\Local\Temp\junit8466679054766850042\ImageMagick\output.jpg
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\chitr\AppData\Local\Temp\junit8466679054766850042\ImageMagick\output.jpg
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:124)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
 at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)

"the file isn't in the location actually"